# Ecto date field striping of timezone info

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have date variable with timezone info. When I insert it into to DB using ecto, it strips off the time zone value and saves. Shouldn’t it instead convert it to UTC before saving to DB? If that’s not default behaviour is there a way to configure it?

```
date = Timex.now("Asia/Kolkata")
user = %User{
    name: "Bob",
    last_login: date,
}
Repo.insert(user)

# user got saved with last_login field with date - striped off timezone info.
# While inserted_at and updated_at always saves the DateTime in UTC.
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `last_login` field has data type of `:naive_datetime` the timezone info will be stripped off without converting time to UTC. Please use `:utc_datetime` instead

### Example:

#### Replace following

```
defmodule SomeModule.Profile do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "profiles" do
    field :login_time, :naive_datetime
    # ...
    timestamps()
  end

end
```

#### With

```
defmodule SomeModule.Profile do
  use Ecto.Schema

  schema "profiles" do
    field :login_time, :utc_datetime
    # ...
    timestamps()
  end

end
```